# How to generate Code with hibernate with list and many to many relationships?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I am generating my Annotated Code Classes with hibernate and eclipse JBoss plugin, For the One to Many & Many to Many Relationships etc, the code generated used Set type for collections and generate many to many as one to many relation.

Project:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Project generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "project", schema = "public")
public class Project implements java.io.Serializable
{

    private int projectId;
    private Type type;
    private Customer customer;
    private String projectName;
    private String description;
    private Double totalContractAmount;
    private Set projectConstructionMaterials = new HashSet( 0 );

    public Project()
    {
    }

    public Project(int projectId)
    {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    public Project(int projectId, Type type, Customer customer, String projectName, String description,
            Double totalContractAmount, 
            Set projectConstructionMaterials)
    {
        this.projectId = projectId;
        this.type = type;
        this.customer = customer;
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.description = description;
        this.totalContractAmount = totalContractAmount;

        this.projectConstructionMaterials = projectConstructionMaterials;
    }

    @Id

    @Column(name = "project_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getProjectId()
    {
        return this.projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(int projectId)
    {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
    public Type getType()
    {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setType(Type type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    public Customer getCustomer()
    {
        return this.customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @Column(name = "project_name")
    public String getProjectName()
    {
        return this.projectName;
    }

    public void setProjectName(String projectName)
    {
        this.projectName = projectName;
    }

    @Column(name = "description", length = 500)
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }



    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "project") //it should be many to many annotation
    public Set getProjectConstructionMaterials()
    {
        return this.projectConstructionMaterials;
    }

    public void setProjectConstructionMaterials(Set projectConstructionMaterials)
    {
        this.projectConstructionMaterials = projectConstructionMaterials;
    }

}
```

ProjectConstructionMaterial

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * ProjectConstructionMaterial generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "project_construction_material", schema = "public")
public class ProjectConstructionMaterial implements java.io.Serializable
{

    private int projectConstructionMaterialId;
    private ConstructionMaterialInventory constructionMaterialInventory;
    private Project project;
    private String description;
    private String quantityArrived;
    private String quantityConsumed;

    public ProjectConstructionMaterial()
    {
    }

    public ProjectConstructionMaterial(int projectConstructionMaterialId)
    {
        this.projectConstructionMaterialId = projectConstructionMaterialId;
    }

    public ProjectConstructionMaterial(int projectConstructionMaterialId,
            ConstructionMaterialInventory constructionMaterialInventory, Project project, String description,
            String quantityArrived, String quantityConsumed)
    {
        this.projectConstructionMaterialId = projectConstructionMaterialId;
        this.constructionMaterialInventory = constructionMaterialInventory;
        this.project = project;
        this.description = description;
        this.quantityArrived = quantityArrived;
        this.quantityConsumed = quantityConsumed;
    }

    @Id

    @Column(name = "project_construction_material_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getProjectConstructionMaterialId()
    {
        return this.projectConstructionMaterialId;
    }

    public void setProjectConstructionMaterialId(int projectConstructionMaterialId)
    {
        this.projectConstructionMaterialId = projectConstructionMaterialId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "construction_material_id")
    public ConstructionMaterialInventory getConstructionMaterialInventory()
    {
        return this.constructionMaterialInventory;
    }

    public void setConstructionMaterialInventory(ConstructionMaterialInventory constructionMaterialInventory)
    {
        this.constructionMaterialInventory = constructionMaterialInventory;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    public Project getProject()
    {
        return this.project;
    }

    public void setProject(Project project)
    {
        this.project = project;
    }

    @Column(name = "description", length = 500)
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Column(name = "quantity_arrived")
    public String getQuantityArrived()
    {
        return this.quantityArrived;
    }

    public void setQuantityArrived(String quantityArrived)
    {
        this.quantityArrived = quantityArrived;
    }

    @Column(name = "quantity_consumed")
    public String getQuantityConsumed()
    {
        return this.quantityConsumed;
    }

    public void setQuantityConsumed(String quantityConsumed)
    {
        this.quantityConsumed = quantityConsumed;
    }

}
```

ConstructionMaterialInventory

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * ConstructionMaterialInventory generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "construction_material_inventory", schema = "public")
public class ConstructionMaterialInventory implements java.io.Serializable
{

    private int constructionMaterialId;
    private Type type;
    private SubType subType;
    private String quantity;
    private String description;
    private Set projectConstructionMaterials = new HashSet( 0 );

    public ConstructionMaterialInventory()
    {
    }

    public ConstructionMaterialInventory(int constructionMaterialId)
    {
        this.constructionMaterialId = constructionMaterialId;
    }

    public ConstructionMaterialInventory(int constructionMaterialId, Type type, SubType subType, String quantity,
            String description, Set projectConstructionMaterials)
    {
        this.constructionMaterialId = constructionMaterialId;
        this.type = type;
        this.subType = subType;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.description = description;
        this.projectConstructionMaterials = projectConstructionMaterials;
    }

    @Id

    @Column(name = "construction_material_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getConstructionMaterialId()
    {
        return this.constructionMaterialId;
    }

    public void setConstructionMaterialId(int constructionMaterialId)
    {
        this.constructionMaterialId = constructionMaterialId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
    public Type getType()
    {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setType(Type type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sub_type_id")
    public SubType getSubType()
    {
        return this.subType;
    }

    public void setSubType(SubType subType)
    {
        this.subType = subType;
    }

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    public String getQuantity()
    {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity)
    {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Column(name = "description", length = 500)
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "constructionMaterialInventory")
    public Set getProjectConstructionMaterials()
    {
        return this.projectConstructionMaterials;
    }

    public void setProjectConstructionMaterials(Set projectConstructionMaterials)
    {
        this.projectConstructionMaterials = projectConstructionMaterials;
    }

}
```

Data Model

[image]

I want to change it to `many to many` annotations and also want to use `List` or `ArrayList` instead of `Set`. Can anyone please tell me how to do this with automatically code generation? Beause i have dozens of table like this and change in tables manually takes too much time..

For Example: Annotation Must be generate automatically as described in this example.
[Many to Many annotation Example](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/)

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231755/how-do-i-get-the-hibernate-reverse-engineering-tools-to-generate-bag-or-list

Comment: Do you have a unique constraint on your join table?

Comment: No, i have no unique constraint